# Ports not accessible in Docker on Mac

Tags: docker, boot2docker

NOTE: I'm a networking noob, so please explain answers accordingly.

I am running boot2docker+VirtualBox on Mac OS.

Launch my Docker container like this:

```
docker run -it -p 80:80 -p 28017:28017 mine/envbox bash
```

In the container I start nginx and mongo.  Then *inside* the container I try:

```
curl localhost:80  // returns content
curl localhost:28017 // returns content
```

So I know my services are up and healthy inside the container.  *Outside* the container on my host I run:

```
curl http://$(boot2docker ip):80  // returns content
curl http://$(boot2docker ip):28017  // connection error
```

I've configured port forwarding on my VirtualBox on my Mac like this: (port 28017 should be exposed)

[image]

Why can't I see port 28017 on my host?

Comment: Output of docker port:``28017/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:28017
80/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:80```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it.  mongodb (the process binding to port 28017) has a config that blocks non-local access by default, so naturally it wouldn't be visible outside the container.  Un-commenting that config resolved the issue.

At least it forced me to upgrade from boot2docker to docker toolbox, so that's a good thing.